# Jsoup removing elements automatically?

Tags: jsoup

I've been using Jsoup for a while but I encountered a bug where Jsoup automatically remove "table" element and can not find any workaround...

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.planet-series.tv/dr-house/").get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

If you navigate to the link in this piece of code, you can see that there is multiple element "table" (for example: under "Saison 01 (VF)", there are 22 table elements containing "Episode x"), yet they are absent in the JSOUP output...

### Expected

[image: table elements]

### Result

[image: Imgur]

I tried to get the document with a simple `HttpClient`, print it (table elements are there), parse it with Jsoup, reprint (table elements are gone) so I know it's not a Javascript issue or whatever and Jsoup is indeed causing it.

Can you tell me what am I missing please?

Answer (score 0):

Some websites will perform optimization/restriction based on the user-agent data (the header the browser attach to the request to inform the website about the type of browser). Some website will block content if the user agent is not set.

You could try to use a simplified mozilla user agent to simulate a real browser and fetch the data:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.planet-series.tv/dr-house/")
                .userAgent("mozilla").get();
System.out.println(doc);
```

If this does not work, and you really hit a bug of JSoup, just fetch the data using HttpClient and then create the document using:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

where `html` is the string containing the page content.

Comment: I tried with the HttpClient (see last but one paragraph) and userAgent: Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); doesn't work here (if I print html tables are there, if I print doc tables are gone)